# Optimization of trace of a matrix

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, pseudoinverse, trace-map

I want to solve the following optimization problem , if R is a positive semi-definite matrix and D is diagonal matrix , both of size T x T then we should solve

${\underset{D}{min}}$ trace[$(R + D)^{\dagger}$]

such that trace(D) $\leq$ P

here $A^{\dagger}$ = Pseudo-inverse of A

Any help using  matrix calculus or lagrange multiplier or any other method is welcome

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\lr{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\lr{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\lr{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\lr{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$To avoid confusion with the differential operator, rename the variable $D\to A$.

Then consider the case when $R=R^T$ and $A_{kk}>0$, then we can dispense with the pseudoinverse and write the objective function as
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{(R+A)^{-1}} \\
d\phi &= -(R+A)^{-2}:dA \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a convenient notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$

Introduce the unconstrained vector $(b)$ and its associated diagonal matrix $(B)$ and scalar magnitude $(\b)$. Then use it to *construct* a matrix which satisfies the constraints (rename the scalar $P\to\a$).
$$\eqalign{
B &= \Diag{b} \quad&\implies\quad \trace{B}=\b \\
\b &= \o^Tb \quad&\implies\quad d\b = \o^Tdb = \trace{dB} \\
A &= \fracLR{\a}{\b} B  \quad&\implies\quad \trace{A}=\a  \\
a &= \fracLR{\a}{\b} b \quad&\implies\quad \o^Ta=\a \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the constructed matrix
$$\eqalign{
da &= \fracLR{\a\b\,db-\a b\,d\b}{\b^2} \\
 &= \frac{\a}{\b^2}\lr{\b I-b\o^T} db \\
}$$
and substituted it into the diagonalized differential of the function
to obtain the unconstrained gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= -\diag{(R+A)^{-2}}:da \\
 &= -g:da \\
 &= -\frac{\a}{\b^2}g:\lr{\b I-b\o^T} db \\
 &= +\frac{\a}{\b^2}\lr{\o b^Tg-\b g}: db \\
\grad{\phi}{b} &= \frac{\a}{\b^2}\lr{\o b^Tg-\b g} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero yields
$$\eqalign{
\lr{\o b^T}g & = \b g \\
}$$
This is an eigenvalue equation for a rank-$\o$ matrix which has a single *non-zero* eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\o$
(the all-ones vector). Therefore $g$ is equal to this eigenvector (or is a scalar multiple of it).
$$\eqalign{
\o &= \lambda g = \diag{\lr{R+A}^{-2}}  \\
I &= \lambda \Diag{\diag{\lr{R+A}^{-2}}} \\
  &= \lambda I\odot\lr{R+A}^{-2}  \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product.

This is a nonlinear equation, but it can be rearranged into an
interative relationship (which hopefully converges)
$$\eqalign{
A_0 &= I \\
Z_+ &= A\odot\lr{R+A}^{-2}  \\
A_+ &= \frac{P\,Z_+}{\trace{Z_+}}
 \qquad&\big({\rm enforce\,the\,constraint}\big)  \\
}$$
Initializing $A$ to a *random* diagonal matrix might improve its convergence prospects.

---

The zero eigenvectors of $(\o b^T)$ are also possible extremal solutions. You can explore them by choosing $g$ to be perpendicular to $b$ (and therefore perpendicular to $a$).

This leads to a very different system of nonlinear equations
$$\eqalign{
f(a) &= a^T\diag{\big[R+\Diag{a}\big]^{-2}} \;\doteq\; 0 \\
}$$
which could be solved using Newton's Method or a Quasi-Newton method.

Comment: how can we get rid of the pseudo inverse and replace it with inverse in the initial steps ?

Comment: @PHANIRAJ Making $R$ and $D$ symmetric and diagonal positive definite are simplifying assumptions. Under those assumptions $(R+D)^{-1}$ exists and is identical to the pseudoinverse.  A gradient can certainly be calculated _without_ those assumptions, but it'll be much more complicated. Before you go down that path: Are you sure that the assumptions are not applicable to your intended purpose?

Comment: yes , they are definitely not applicable in my case